# Angular Loop on fetched observable array data and fetch another array of data in it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello I have an API call `getItems()` that return data like this :

```
[
 {
   name: 'item1',
   materials: [
     1,
     2,
     3,
   ],
 },
 {
   name: 'item2',
   materials: [
     2,
     3,
     6,
   ],
 }
 ...
]
```

And another API call `getMaterial(id)` that return the data of a material like this :

```
{
  name: 'mat1',
  img: '/img.jpg'
}
```

What I'm try to achieve is to get all the items data with the materials data. I manage to have all the observable call for materials but I don't know what to do after.

That's what I've done so far :

```
public getAllItemsData(): Observable<any> {
  return getItems().pipe(
    map((list: items[]) => {
      return list.map(item => {
        const allMat = item.materials.map(m => getMaterial(m))

        return forkJoin(allMat).pipe(
          map(data => {
            return {
              ...item,
              materials: data
            }
          })
        )
      })
    }),
  );
}
```

But it's not working. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.
Using [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap), [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap), [from](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from), [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)

```
getItems()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((items) =>
        // for each items
      from(items).pipe(
       // merge map to run parallel for each items
        mergeMap(({ materials, ...item }) =>
        // wait to retrive all materials details of current item at mergeMap
        // after completing use map to map item with retrived materials 
          forkJoin(
            materials.map((m) => this.getMaterial(m))
          ).pipe(map((materialDetails) => ({ ...item, materials: materialDetails })))
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without switchMap, to make it easier (I shouldn't have) I ommit the point that I'm using firestore valuechange which mean there is an active stream and I feel like the switchMap causing problems in this solution ! I have no errors, but I have no output data.

Comment: If You can generate on stackblitz. I can help you easily

Comment: Here you go : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbdfnk?file=src/app/farmloc.service.ts

Comment: error `Can't find package:@angular/fire`.. Can you share some JSON data instead? Or should i come up with demo example with data from `question`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237992/discussion-between-imad-el-hitti-and-navnath).

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the above just with less nested pipes

```
interface Item {
    name: string;
    materials: number[];
}

interface MaterialData {
    name: string;
    img: string;
}

public getAllItemsData() {
    return getItems().pipe(
        switchMap((items: Item[]) => from(items)), // use 'from' to deal with one Item at a time
        mergeMap(({ materials, name }: Item) =>
            forkJoin(materials.map((mat) => getMaterial(mat))) // create array of observables using map, and pass into forkJoin 
                .pipe(
                    map((materials) => ({ name, materials })), // reconstruct object
                ),
        ),
        toArray(), // collect all emissions and output as an array
    );
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without switchMap, to make it easier (I shouldn't have) I ommit the point that I'm using firestore valuechange which mean there is an active stream and I feel like the switchMap causing problems in this solution ! I have no errors, but I have no output data

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a final merge/forkJoin to subscribe to the array of observables you've created.

```ts
public getAllItemsData(): Observable<any> {

  return getItems().pipe(

    map((list: items[]) => 
      list.map(item => 
        forkJoin(
          item.materials.map(m => getMaterial(m))
        ).pipe(
          map(materials => ({
            ...item,
            materials
          }))
        )
      )
    ),

    // Subscribe to the list created above
    mergeMap((list:Observable<any>[]) => forkJoin(list))

  );

}
```